# Euler characteristic of the generic fiber of a homogeneous polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb C^n\to \mathbb C$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $>1$.
Can it happen that the Euler characteristic of $f^{-1}(x)$ for $x\neq 0$ is equal to 1? The answer seems to be "no" but I would be glad to see either a proof or a reference (or a counterexample). Same question when $\mathbb C$ is replaced by a field of characteristic $p$ with the condition that $f$ is not a $p$-th power of another polynomial.

Comment: If the homogeneous degree equals $d$, then there is a action of the $d$th roots of unity on $\mathbb{C}^n$ by scaling.  The only point with nontrivial stabilizer is the origin, and $f(0)$ equals $0$.  For every $x\neq 0$, $f^{-1}(x)$ is preserved by the action, and so it has a free action of this finite group.  Thus, the Euler characteristic of the fiber equals $d$ times the Euler characteristic of its quotient by this group action.

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed this trivial point. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, I spent fifteen minutes trying to find a counterexample before I realized this :)

Answer (score 3):

I am just posting my comment above as an answer.

There is an action of $\mu_d$, the group of $d$th roots of unity on $\mathbb{A}^n$.  The unique point in $\mathbb{A}^n$ with nontrivial stabilizer subgroup is the origin $0$, and $f(0)$ equals $0$.  Thus, for every fiber $f^{-1}(x)$ other than the fiber of the origin, there is a free action of $\mu_d$ on $f^{-1}(x)$.  So the Euler characteristic of $f^{-1}(x)$ equals $d$ times the Euler characteristic of the free quotient $f^{-1}(x)/\mu_d$.

The quotient $f^{-1}(x)/\mu_d$ can have Euler characteristic $1$, e.g., if $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = x_1^d$ or $x_1^d + x_2x_3^{d-1}$, etc.